# JSON-LD with HYDRA: how to define a custom operation and specify its URL?

Tags: rest, json-ld, hydra-core

I have a resource accessible under somebaseurl/myresource/id123
That resource has of course some properties, some links to other resources, but it has also some supported operations.
So far, so good.
As long as these operations correspond to http verbs performed on the url of the resource at somebaseurl/myresource/id123, everything is ok.
But what if I defined some special action, accessible by issuing a POST on somebaseurl/myresource/id123/somespecialaction ?
How do I represent this within the resource ?
JSON-LD+Hydra has no support for actions, hydra has support for operations, but I cannot specify an "endpoint" or "URL" property for the operation within a resource.
So I am limited to operation accessible by somebaseurl/myresource/id123 (all HTTP verbs, nothing else)
How can I leave these boundaries within the resource representation?

```
{
  "@context":"https://contexts.dictionary.mycompany-group.com/person.jsonld",
  "@id":"https://myapi.mycompany.com/persons/BE14A7269802498F992813885546D058",
  "@type":"https://schema.org/Person",
  "name": "Mustermann",
  "operation"
    : [
      {"@type": "DeleteResourceOperation","method": "DELETE"},
      {"@type": "ReplaceResourceOperation","method": "PUT"}
      ],
    // now how would one specify this with JSON-LD augmented by HYDRA?

    {"@type": "some_special_operation","method": "POST", URL:"https://myapi.mycompany.com/persons/BE14A7269802498F992813885546D058/some_special_operation"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I m looking for a way to specify an operation on a particular resource
>   instance: the operation's URL and HTTP method should be specifiable.
>   Example (please check the last 3 lines):
>
> {
>
> "@context":"https://contexts.dictionary.mycompany-group.com/person.jsonld",
>
> "@id":"https://myapi.mycompany.com/persons/BE14A7269802498F992813885546D058"
>   ,
>     "@type":"https://schema.org/Person",
>     "name": "Mustermann",
>     "operation": [
>         {"@type": "DeleteResourceOperation","method": "DELETE"},
>         {"@type": "ReplaceResourceOperation","method": "PUT"}
>         ],
>
> // now how would one specify this with JSON-LD augmented by HYDRA?

You need to reference the other " some_special_operation " from the node
above or create a new top-level node with that operation

> {
>       "@type": "some_special_operation",
>       "method": "POST",
>
> URL:"https://myapi.mycompany.com/persons/BE14A7269802498F992813885546D058/so
>   me_special_operation"
>     }
>   }

So either

```
  BE14A7269802498F992813885546D058
    - operation: delete + put

  5546D058/some_special_operation
    - operation: post
```

or

```
  BE14A7269802498F992813885546D058
    - operation: delete + put
    - relationshipProperty:
      ... 5546D058/some_special_operation
         - operation: post
```

where you would pick some property for "relationshipProperty" that describes
the relationship between the two resources.

That being said, we are currently trying to simplify this, see https://github.com/HydraCG/Specifications/issues/3

Comment: Thanks - I cant vote your question up due to the fact that the stack* community is evaluating me at beginner level ;))